# Could there be a message that a question is deleted while editing a snippet

Tags: feature-request

I was answering a question, and while I was creating a snippet to make things understandable that question was deleted.

That could happen, but I have a feeling that I've spend too much time working on that snippet while the question was already gone. Snippets hide the fact that a question is deleted since the red banner is underneath it.

Could there be some popup showing the question is deleted? I realise throwing away that snippet might be painful for some people if they made something pretty, but a simple `alert` would be sufficient I guess.

Comment: There is a message box shown at the top when the question gets deleted, IIRC but the z-index of the snippet editor is so high that the messagebox never gets shown on top of the snippet editor.

Comment: I had the same once. lost 15 minutes of composing the answer.